# Docker on a linux VM, performances?

Tags: linux, performance, docker

I would like to know what Docker on VM implies regarding the performances, will I have issue ?

To me, adding a "layer" would decrease the performances. Is it right or wrong and most importantly, why ?

I want to be able to know what is the best way to deal with new projects when containers are on the line.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome so SO. your question is very broad, no so good for [SO guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) However docker is an abstraction layer to run applications on cloud providers, and they run VMs. So running docker in a VM is just best practice. For example: https://aws.amazon.com/docker/

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but unfortunatly it's not helpful. Just saying "they run VMs so it's best practice" doesn't tell me why.
By making some search, most time you just find "Containers VS VM" and just few people talk about both working together, and even less having real arguments to tell what is the best.
I was looking for something like David's answer. Like it doesn't matter if you the system needs to make more calls because in the end you ll wait for JVMs and / or databases or something like that.
But you're right my question was too broad.

Comment: I think the link @AWS is really self-exaplainatory. Why? Because of scalability. Both Docker and cloud are not there to obtain best-performance. Write you monolithic applications in native C for that. So you must be happy to pay for overheads in both docker and VMs to gain in terms of scalability. Furthermore, how can you evaluate the weight of a layer, without knowing what kind of resources your application is based on? VMs are an overhead yes, than? Are they worthwhile for electricity companies only, in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

Every part of the system stack has some performance cost, but it’s probably close to immeasurable.  In what you describe the cost of the VM will probably be greater than the cost of Docker, but the cost of either will be dwarfed by the cost of any database I/O you do.  As always database tuning and algorithmic tuning will probably make the biggest difference.

An additional layer in a Docker image has approximately zero performance impact.  It’s mildly “nicer” to have fewer layers but it doesn’t really matter that much.

If your program is in an interpreted language like Ruby or Python, or if you’re frequently starting JVMs, the performance difference from using a virtual machine or not is noise compared to the sheer overhead of these systems.

As always, the real answer is to run real benchmarks, and profile the system/application if it’s too slow.  The sorts of questions you’re asking aren’t things you need to optimize for early and often aren’t things you need to optimize for at all.

Comment: Hello David, Thanks for your anwser, totally what I was looking for!